# Why in watson studio you don´t have the option to deploy a model web or upload a batch?

Tags: watson-studio

I had create and save a model in watson studio, at the moment of deploy i can´t only have the Webdeploy option and not the upload a batch option. 
Second if i deploy de model in web and test it it only accepts json and not the forms options.

Does anyone know why?
Thanks in advance
JP

Comment: Because it's not implemented? If you want to request features or point out problems in IBM Watson Studio, you'll have to contact IBM directly, through support tickets or suggestions at https://ibm.biz/IBM-Data-and-AI-Ideas

Comment: How did you create the model in Watson Studio? The deployment and scoring capabilities of the models vary depending upon the type of models and the tool used to create them.

Comment: Auto AI Experiment.  Onces, finish i just select the best scoring to deploy and in the deployment i have only the option Web Deploy